# How to import DomParser Object in chrome extension with manifest v3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, domparser

I found a lot of third-party libraries, but they are all based on nodejs. How can I use them in Chrome extension v3 service_worker?

Comment: ManifestV3 doesn't have an API to parse HTML in the service worker yet, see https://crbug.com/1056354. Workarounds depend on what you want to do with the data so please add a more detailed description to the question and show your manifest.json's `content_scripts`, whether its `host_permissions` include all sites, and whether it has the `activeTab` permission.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks your answer, I want to parse the HTML string in the service_worker script and then extract the text value of the element. Although it can be achieved through regular expressions, it is not as concise as Domparser. So I will wait for chromium to add Domparser support as much as possible, until the death line of v2, if not, I will use regular expressions to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I had found the answer: [cheeriojs/cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)